# '_BoundDeclarativeMeta' object is not iterable' error in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a Flask app that will display the amount and content of emails sent by Presidential campaigns. I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy to create a database to hold the emails.  The `models.py` file I'm working from looks like this:

```
from app import db

class Politician(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    emails = db.relationship('Email', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Politician %s>' % self.name

class Email(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    sender_id = db.Column(db.String(10000), db.ForeignKey('politician.name'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<E-mail %s>' % self.body
```

The database is populated the way I'd like it to be, so the problem isn't there.  I'm getting the `_BoundDeclarativeMeta` error from my `views.py` file, which looks like this:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app
from .models import Politician, Email

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    posts = [i.body for i in Email]
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           posts=posts)
```

I can gather from the error message that when I refer to `Email` in `views.py`, I shouldn't use the model name, but I'm not quite sure how to access the emails themselves from the database.  Do any of you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a dope - it was an easy fix.  I got it to work by changing the posts list comprehension to `posts = [i.body for i in Email.query.all()]`.